how to use collab in python script
On Python: Please send URL of a Google Colab containing a Python script that does the following:

Retrieve the description text from https://youtu.be/iTmlw3vQPSs using Selenium

Extract all the timestamps using regex (assuming the format is mm:ss), and save them in a list.

Store url: str, timestamp_list: str in text file and email it as well.


I want code or how to do
and output problem

This is not a code writing service. See: How do I do X? The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]
